# What colors I am looking for in the TSA stain in this paper?

Tags: lab-techniques, histology, lab-reagents

I'm just having a little bit of trouble and want to make sure that I am seeing the same things that the original researchers were seeing. This is the name of the paper [Hair Cycle Control by Estrogens: Catagen Induction via Estrogen Receptor (ER)-α Is Checked by ERβ Signaling](https://watermark.silverchair.com/endo1214.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAsIwggK-BgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggKvMIICqwIBADCCAqQGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMKL8hC_eTbjzkhsOTAgEQgIICdfCs6k_5YksN2D89s9QJf5f4VAiTgK4YcPt2hMe9XqcZFSxDmWx-rl-jBEQHHUoTeuk731htrPc9x5RgkmOpAMLiuGlBtWdEI7YgWqdNPAZ21nW28Kv1raVu5TnW0mp9GaEb4UPZuHTzz2CaKAYlBZPS0Yp1kczjNFotHpcyCopvfLxgMiTw4rnVLjw0t0sikvgjFWW4BvHir6iXrn5ows_YXDK6LUXuAlw1xbGlfRP8n8gOwstZ1t_qnEr5QhPLCbUc9DMjhXjpq0rEz2051Gvdbn7CfgIoHXVUpNwAtpHx6XsxBMsFc2J1SgjK8HYGHm6cA9LXpPhWGet4-wxlxm-cx4rwHmJuqr8eVY8LMXC41gLjb0iBMwNur9nGNiINiePRUjPgNBVf-6xMDPXqRvHGHq8_DhYPZtaZ2gEqMg4E6ByU13iUn_fUpcZEjJU3JYFktk0xVLpUR5T-fNCwfHeYmmHa4nhkpQYP4KbVKLfN8fxGl6_m9OJjm8qDTt08PIM6uegYGQpB6Eafj-aRS5xQicKGm6LAZ3O4mo7BAB9ssqAMUY_c3cZNSb0LvY2NuQSLrXUWcOPERtAlc3mMPDxPhLNRYSUPa6dM7nfLDDDeaaZz4nmTRu6IxI4HEunfJnGEki1tgxSeAMAbmPpMRHFKSL-XdMk-vrEAs_AHZB3NH6_z9aMvA66SvD0getVwnldRi06uGc1tcK0Ufj5QV2cjUYuZpOmq88rJ6nujEsiXCrxoAcZcc84notmEdJcwKYuUvIlgUORep9Cdpx5tdG_J1Y2KunwoK5CUVLfC4QkZLgq5kc05U15NhHO7EQisxtg1F57A). Specifically, I am looking at Figure 2 with the tyramine signal amplification (TSA) images and am wondering what colors are supposed to indicate the presence of estrogen receptor (ER)? Take the statement:

> ERα IR had its peak in telogen follicles and was intensely visible in
> the dermal papilla and cells of the sebaceous gland.

When I look at Figure 2, T, I don't seem to be seeing any blue in the sebaceous gland?

[image: https://ibb.co/HTWqmPp]

Is it the case that the area I circled in red is the sebaceous gland with the smaller circles around the blue indicating the presence of ER-α, as opposed to the arrow the authors had placed?

[image]